# How to click this button using selenium webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape the data table from nasdaq: https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/msft/interactive-chart?timeframe=5d

What I do is using python and selenium webdriver to click the table button(on top of the chart, with a little table logo) and then scrape.

```py
submit = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#dataTableBtn')))
submit.click()
```

But it does not work.

Button html here:

```
<div id="dataTableBtn" class="btn hideSmallIR stx-collapsible" onclick="dataTableLoader()"><span>Data Table</span></div>
```

EC and By

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Its inside `<iframe>`, you need to switch to it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *chart* and the associated elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/msft/interactive-chart?timeframe=5d")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src*='edgar-chartiq']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.hideSmallIR#dataTableBtn>span"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/msft/interactive-chart?timeframe=5d")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src, 'edgar-chartiq')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='btn hideSmallIR stx-collapsible' and @id='dataTableBtn']/span[text()='Data Table']"))).click()
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: nasdaq_datatable]

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Why don't you use `'#chartholder > iframe'` as the CSS SELECTOR?

Comment: @MosheSlavin From a generic approach, the search for a direct `iframe` tag will be much more faster. However `'#chartholder > iframe'` would also work.

Comment: Yes it works! I am new to web scraping so I am not familiar with iframe. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @DebanjanB Your locator to find the IFRAME vs MosheSlavin's will be negligible in speed difference. Where are you getting, `the search for a direct iframe tag will be much more faster`?

Answer (score 1):

The table is in an `iframe`, so just switch to it!

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#chartholder > iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

You can use `WebDriverWait` with `EC` like this:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#chartholder > iframe')
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(frame))
```

Answer (score -1):

The button you're looking for belongs to an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) so you will have to [switch](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) to it prior to attempting to find the button.

Both iframe and the button can be located using [XPath contains() function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'edgar-chartiq')]"))
```

Once you're in the iframe you should be able to locate and click the button:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Data Table')]").click()
```

Comment: Why use `XPath` and `contains()` when you can use CSS?